# How would I calculate the heat change of compressed air?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, ideal-gas, applied-physics

My friend is working on a snow gun, which involves using compressed air to blow apart water coming out of a pressure washer. I read that you can cool air by compressing it, which makes it hot, then letting the compressed air lose energy by cooling to room temperature.

I was going to use the ideal gas law to find the change in temperature when compressed/decompressed, and Newton's law of cooling to find the time it'd take to cool down. However, I don't think the ideal gas law can be used in this case.
What equations are appropriate to find the temperature of a gas before and after it is compressed?

Comment: [Adiabatic compression/expansion of an ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process#Ideal_gas_\(reversible_process\)).

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thank you!